# How to declare typealias and enum in swift?

Tags: swift, enums, typedef

I pulled this example from Lynda and am trying to convert it to Swift but having errors. Would anyone have any ideas how to successfully convert this to Swift?

Objective-C

```
typedef enum { window = 99, aisle = 199, middle = 399 } seatPreference;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {

    seatPreference bobSeatPreference = aisle;
    seatPreference fredSeatPreference = window;


    if (bobSeatPreference == window) {
        // do something
    }

    NSLog(@"Fred wants %i", fredSeatPreference);
```

Swift so far

```
typealias enum { case Window = 99, case Aisle = 199, case Middle = 399 } = seatPreference

import Foundation

seatPreference bobSeatPreference = aisle
seatPreference fredSeatPreference = window

if (bobSeatPreference == window) {
    // do something
}

printLn(“Fred wants \(fredSeatPreference)”)
```

Answer (score 0):

`typedef enum` turns into a Swift `enum`.
Your code could be rewritten as follows:

```
enum SeatPreference:Int {
    case Window = 99
    case Aisle = 199
    case Middle = 399
}

var bobSeatPreference:SeatPreference = .Aisle
var fredSeatPreference:SeatPreference = .Window

if (bobSeatPreference == .Window) {
    // do something
}

SeatPreference.Window.toRaw() //this prints 99
```